# Nginx in docker container not serving static files

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, nginx-config

I recently took over someone's project and I am supposed to deploy it to a new server. There is an Nginx server serving the static files of a Django app. I keep getting a 404-not-found error from Nginx. Here is the Nginx.conf file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 150M;

    include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    location /static {
        sendfile  on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 25m;
        alias /static;
    }

    location /media/user {
        sendfile  on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 50m;
        internal;
        alias /media/user;
    }

    location /admin/login {
        return 301 " /login";
    }

    location /media/protected {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* (360Spider|80legs.com|Abonti|AcoonBot|Acunetix|adbeat_bot|AddThis.com|adidxbot|ADmantX|AhrefsBot|AngloINFO|Antelope|Applebot|BaiduSpider|BeetleBot|billigerbot|binlar|bitlybot|BlackWidow|BLP_bbot|BoardReader|Bolt\ 0|BOT\ for\ JCE|Bot\ mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com|casper|CazoodleBot|CCBot|checkprivacy|ChinaClaw|chromeframe|Clerkbot|Cliqzbot|clshttp|CommonCrawler|comodo|CPython|crawler4j|Crawlera|CRAZYWEBCRAWLER|Curious|Curl|Custo|CWS_proxy|Default\ Browser\ 0|diavol|DigExt|Digincore|DIIbot|discobot|DISCo|DoCoMo|DotBot|Download\ Demon|DTS.Agent|EasouSpider|eCatch|ecxi|EirGrabber|Elmer|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|Exabot|ExaleadCloudView|ExpertSearchSpider|ExpertSearch|Express\ WebPictures|ExtractorPro|extract|EyeNetIE|Ezooms|F2S|FastSeek|feedfinder|FeedlyBot|FHscan|finbot|Flamingo_SearchEngine|FlappyBot|FlashGet|flicky|Flipboard|g00g1e|Genieo|genieo|GetRight|GetWeb\!|GigablastOpenSource|GozaikBot|Go\!Zilla|Go\-Ahead\-Got\-It|GrabNet|grab|Grafula|GrapeshotCrawler|GTB5|GT\:\:WWW|Guzzle|harvest|heritrix|HMView|HomePageBot|HTTP\:\:Lite|HTTrack|HubSpot|ia_archiver|icarus6|IDBot|id\-search|IlseBot|Image\ Stripper|Image\ Sucker|Indigonet|Indy\ Library|integromedb|InterGET|InternetSeer\.com|Internet\ Ninja|IRLbot|ISC\ Systems\ iRc\ Search\ 2\.1|jakarta|Java|JetCar|JobdiggerSpider|JOC\ Web\ Spider|Jooblebot|kanagawa|KINGSpider|kmccrew|larbin|LeechFTP|libwww|Lingewoud|LinkChecker|linkdexbot|LinksCrawler|LinksManager\.com_bot|linkwalker|LinqiaRSSBot|LivelapBot|ltx71|LubbersBot|lwp\-trivial|Mail.RU_Bot|masscan|Mass\ Downloader|maverick|Maxthon$|Mediatoolkitbot|MegaIndex|MegaIndex|megaindex|MFC_Tear_Sample|Microsoft\ URL\ Control|microsoft\.url|MIDown\ tool|miner|Missigua\ Locator|Mister\ PiX|mj12bot|Mozilla.*Indy|Mozilla.*NEWT|MSFrontPage|msnbot|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|netEstate|NetSpider|NetZIP|Net\ Vampire|NextGenSearchBot|nutch|Octopus|Offline\ Explorer|Offline\ Navigator|OpenindexSpider|OpenWebSpider|OrangeBot|Owlin|PageGrabber|PagesInventory|panopta|panscient\.com|Papa\ Foto|pavuk|pcBrowser|PECL\:\:HTTP|PeoplePal|Photon|PHPCrawl|planetwork|PleaseCrawl|PNAMAIN.EXE|PodcastPartyBot|prijsbest|proximic|psbot|purebot|pycurl|QuerySeekerSpider|R6_CommentReader|R6_FeedFetcher|RealDownload|ReGet|Riddler|Rippers\ 0|rogerbot|RSSingBot|rv\:1.9.1|RyzeCrawler|SafeSearch|SBIder|Scrapy|Scrapy|Screaming|SeaMonkey$|search.goo.ne.jp|SearchmetricsBot|search_robot|SemrushBot|Semrush|SentiBot|SEOkicks|SeznamBot|ShowyouBot|SightupBot|SISTRIX|sitecheck\.internetseer\.com|siteexplorer.info|SiteSnagger|skygrid|Slackbot|Slurp|SmartDownload|Snoopy|Sogou|Sosospider|spaumbot|Steeler|sucker|SuperBot|Superfeedr|SuperHTTP|SurdotlyBot|Surfbot|tAkeOut|Teleport\ Pro|TinEye-bot|TinEye|Toata\ dragostea\ mea\ pentru\ diavola|Toplistbot|trendictionbot|TurnitinBot|turnit|Twitterbot|URI\:\:Fetch|urllib|Vagabondo|Vagabondo|vikspider|VoidEYE|VoilaBot|WBSearchBot|webalta|WebAuto|WebBandit|WebCollage|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebGo\ IS|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|Website\ eXtractor|Website\ Quester|WebStripper|WebWhacker|WebZIP|Web\ Image\ Collector|Web\ Sucker|Wells\ Search\ II|WEP\ Search|WeSEE|Wget|Widow|WinInet|woobot|woopingbot|worldwebheritage.org|Wotbox|WPScan|WWWOFFLE|WWW\-Mechanize|Xaldon\ WebSpider|XoviBot|yacybot|Yahoo|YandexBot|Yandex|YisouSpider|zermelo|Zeus|zh-CN|ZmEu|ZumBot|ZyBorg) ) {
            return 410;
        }
        sendfile  on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 50m;
        internal;
        alias /media/protected;
    }

    location /media {
        sendfile  on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 25m;
        alias /media;
    }

    location /media/images/company {
        alias /media/images/company;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

This is running in a docker container on a Linux machine. It would a huge help if someone can save me!

EDIT: Here is the DJango media and static configurations in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_server'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

SENDFILE_BACKEND = 'sendfile.backends.nginx'


SENDFILE_ROOT = '/media/'
SENDFILE_URL = '/media/'
```

I navigated inside the docker container of Nginx and found that the files actually exist but I am still getting 404!
Big thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: post the media file url that is getting 404 and django media settings

Comment: There are many possibilities. To begin with, are the static files supposed to be mounted by the Nginx container? Is there a volume for the static files? Or are they built in the container hosting Nginx?

Comment: @K.Railis Thanks for answering! It's inside the Nginx container! when trying to access:https://ace-concordia.com/media/protected/2020/Aly_Gasser_40135687/transcript/9c0be77746d84dceaec44dc2e5b64b07/Sample.pdf 
 If i go to the directory /media/protected/2020/Aly_Gasser_40135687/transcript/9c0be77746d84dceaec44dc2e5b64b07/ inside the Nginx container, the file is actually there! I am thinking maybe it's a permission issue, any ideas?

Comment: @K.Railis
There seems also that there's nothing about this in the error logs but the access logs show it and that it got a 404 response

Comment: @PankajSharma Hi thanks for answering! I updated it!
example.com/media/protected/2020/Aly_Gasser_40135687/transcript/9c0be77746d84dceaec44dc2e5b64b07/Sample.pdf
and this is the link I am accessing! The file is there I navigated to the dir and found it

Comment: @GasserA this is looking correct, please confirm that file is on its correct location

Comment: @PankajSharma it's, as a matter of fact I can access the file when I remove the "internal" part in the ngnix.conf at location /media/protected